# Is it possible to use Django template block from one file to another file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have one template called `skeleton.html`

```
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Some other code
    </div>
    <div>
        {% block contact_info %}
        {% endblock contact_info %}
    </div>
</body>
```

And my other view is say `home.html`

```
{% extends "skeleton.html" %}
{% block contact_info %}
<div class="overflow-hidden">
    <h4>Phone</h4>
    <p class="lead">
       {{ phone }}
    </p>
</div>
{% endblock contact_info %}
```

So is this possible that I can use the block (contact_info) to any other template? Is there any way to reuse and render this block to another template file (e.g about.html)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use include 
for example 
in your  **main template**

```
{% include 'yourapp/yourtemplate.html' %}
```